# Grand Cherokee 2006 Laredo Transmission issue

Tags: transmission, automatic-transmission, jeep, grand-cherokee

I have a 2006 Grand Cherokee Laredo with issues with the transmission. It was working perfect and with no issues and after one day, I started the car and shifter is moving ok and selecting the right gear on the dashboard, but the car does not move. I thought it could be the cold weather but nothing changed after leaving the engine on for almost an hour... I checked the oil and its level is ok and visually looks ok. What it could be? Car is not showing any sign of anything else malfunctioning, or any noise prior to this.

Just to leave it clear.. Engine revs up, the shifter moves ok and the dashboard shows the correct selection, but the transmission feels like it is just in parked, no change in the acceleration or noise that lets you know that the gear has engaged... nothing!

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Is the Jeep 4WD?

Comment: Yes it is @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2

Comment: Did you check the transmission oil level or the engine oil level?

Comment: I did check both, yes and they are ok visually with the right level as per the sticks show @SolarMike

Comment: It is very weird as the last time  (this is the third time that happened, and we have taken it to the garage and nothing comes up like failure code or something the car moves perfect) we had this issue after few minutes the transmission engaged and we said that it could be the cold weather, but since yesterday we haven't had any luck... it is not moving at all! @SolarMike

Comment: @Sheeyla sorry, had to ask - some don’t know they are separate.. may be the shift mechanism has slipped or the 4wd selector has gone into neutral?

Comment: @SolarMike how can I check if any of these two have happened?

Comment: Have you tried moving the 4wd selector?

Comment: no, not at all @SolarMike

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/107927/discussion-between-sheeyla-and-solar-mike).

Answer (score 1):

Replace the filter.  Be very careful with the O-ring around the pickup tube.  If you are sucking in air, you will not be moving.  A lot of transmission shops refuse to even open the pan because the liability, insist that they change the filters and the seal.

When you are under there, you can visually inspect the pan.  If nothing is in the pan, the transmission is probably mechanically OK.  Your only other option then is the valve body (see Ebay and buy another one).

Comment: Thanks! we did that, we insist the transmission shop to do that and we believed they did... at the end it was the pump not getting the pressure up inside the transmission, so we had to replace it... :o( difficult when you don't have the ways to do the work yourself or to be around somene to check it with you.. thanks again for your input!